# py2exe fails to resolve ibm_db dependency (DLL)

Tags: python-2.7, db2, py2exe

I am trying to create an EXE using py2exe for a desktop app I wrote with python 2.7.
The app utilizes ibm_db (v2.0.7), which installs to site-packages as an .egg folder.
The contents of the ibm_db.py file are very short, as the logic itself is implemented in the DLL:

```
import os
if 'clidriver' not in os.environ['PATH']:
    os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ";" + os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'clidriver', 'bin')
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'ibm_db_dlls\ibm_db.dll')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

When I ran py2exe on the project, the dependency on ibm_db wasn’t properly handled (the DLL wasn’t taken into the dist), so running the exe file stumbles upon the following error:

```
...
  File "ibm_db.pyc", line 10, in <module>
  File "ibm_db.pyc", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I tried to copy the DLL manually into the dist folder (both directly and under ibm_db_dlls subfolder), but it’s of no use.
I found this page, and realized that py2exe has an issue with eggs:
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs

As far as I understand, unzipping the egg is not the way to go in my case, because my program does use pkg_resources (through ibm_db.py). Still, I tried installing ibm_db via easy_setup with the --always-unzip option, but the installation gave me this error:

```
Not a URL, existing file, or requirement spec: '--always-unzip'
```

and it was still installed as an .egg.
So I’m looking at the “Including .egg files in your dist directory” option, and wondering whether it can help. And if so – where to start?

I’m using this simple setup.py for running py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['MyApp.py'])
```

What is this “TurboGears” mentioned there? It doesn’t look like something I’m using in my app.

Any advice will be appreciated.
Thanks.